# Probability of two events occurring when we know the sum of both occuring

Tags: probability

I have a question that gives the probability of each event occurring and the probability of either events occurring. But I do not understand how the given probability of either events occurring allows us to determine the probability of just the second event occuring.

> Given we have the events P(A) = $\frac{3}{5}$ and P(B) = $\frac{1}{4}$. Find P(A' $\cap$ B), when P(A $\cup$ B) = $\frac{3}{4}$.

I do not understand either how P(A $\cup$ B) = $\frac{3}{4}$ when P(A) $+$ P(B) = $\frac{17}{20}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $A\cap B= A\cup(A^{\small\complement}\cap B)$ where $A$ and $A^{\small\complement}\cap B$ are disjoint events, so since the probability for a union of *disjoint* events equals the sum of the probabilities for those events:$$\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(A^{\small\complement}\cap B)$$

---

> I do not understand either how $P(A ∪ B) = 3/4$ when $P(A) + P(B) = 17/20$.

This simply indicates that $A$ and $B$ are *not* disjoint events; ie: their intersection is not empty.

Answer (score 3):

Use the principle of inclusion-exclusion:
$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$